# Flash distortion in IE9

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-9, distortion

My customer reported strange problem with flash in ie9 (9.0.8112.16421). Here is a screenshot of the result: http://i46.tinypic.com/f41ens.jpg. The flash app is for internal use only, so I cannot provide an url. This effect occurs after some clicks in the app but on obviously same places. The problem is not reproducable by few testers.

What is the reason?

My assumptions are:

- flash is not up to date?
- graphics driver problem?
- the page viewed with zoom (bottom right corner), maybe a reason?

Thanks and regards

Comment: You could eliminate some of your suspected culprits of the problem: 1) does the problem occur when not zoomed? has the client checked for updated video drivers? Are they using the latest version of Flash Player?

Comment: The problem is now solved - zoom was the reason.
@Sunil, this is of course, the first step that comes to mind. The Problem is, that the customer got this screenshot from his customer:) It is a b2b app. So asking to change something in two hops is difficult. So the decision was to get a precise solution here first.

Comment: @wvxvw, there is a large jpg delivered from backend and embeded into flash. <embed width="100%" height="100%" flashvars="clientHeight=593&amp;clientWidth=1366" wmode="transparent" menu="false" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="main" id="main" src="main.swf?070812" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> is how the flash loaded. Is there a way to prevent this effect when a user having zoom?